# HAProxy + keepalived + multiple backend farms / virtual IP addresses

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, keepalived, backend

we have several backend farms (HTTP, FTP, etc), basically one farm for each customer, and I am about to rebuild our load balancing infrastructure, moving from **`Piranha`** to **`HAProxy`**.

Since we are using **several different backend server farms**, the Piranha config currently looks like this (example shows farm **webserv01**, 2nd farm **webserv02** uses same config, but different virtual IP):

```
virtual webserv01 {
active = 1
address = 10.11.11.1 eth2:30
vip_nmask = 255.255.255.0
port = 80
send = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
expect = "HTTP"
use_regex = 0
load_monitor = none
scheduler = rr
protocol = tcp
timeout = 6
reentry = 15
quiesce_server = 0
server webserv01v {
address = 192.168.101.64
active = 1
port = 80
weight = 1
}
server webserv02v {
address = 192.168.102.64
active = 1
port = 80
weight = 1
}
server webserv05v {
address = 192.168.101.65
active = 1
port = 80
weight = 1
}
server webserv06v {
address = 192.168.102.65
active = 1
port = 80
weight = 1
}
}
```

(e.g., customer 1 has his own webserver farm using vIP 10.11.11.1:80, customer 2 has a farm using vIP 10.11.11.2:80). I am curious if 1 single HAProxy instance is capable of handling multiple farms of the same service using different unique vIP addresses. 


Basic setup would look like this:

2 HAProxy instances (with failover)
4 HTTP backend farms (one for each customer)
2 FTP farms

To make things clearer, please find attached my concept HAProxy config example for 2 webserver farms. Notice the different virtual IPs:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# LB: VIRTUAL WEBSERVER POOL #01
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend vWEB-LB-01
bind    10.11.11.1:80
mode    http
default_backend vWEB-Pool-01

backend vWEB-Pool-01
mode    http
balance roundrobin
server  webserv01v  192.168.101.64:80   check   weight 100  inter 1000
server  webserv02v  192.168.102.64:80   check   weight 100  inter 1000
server  webserv05v  192.168.101.65:80   check   weight 100  inter 1000
server  webserv06v  192.168.102.65:80   check   weight 100  inter 1000

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# LB: VIRTUAL WEBSERVER POOL #02
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend vWEB-LB-02
bind    10.11.11.2:80
mode    http
default_backend vWEB-Pool-02

backend vWEB-Pool-02
mode    http
balance roundrobin
server  webserv01v  192.168.101.75:80   check   weight 100  inter 1000
server  webserv02v  192.168.101.76:80   check   weight 100  inter 1000
server  webserv05v  192.168.101.68:80   check   weight 100  inter 1000
server  webserv06v  192.168.101.69:80   check   weight 100  inter 1000
```

Can HAProxy and/or keeoalived handle this the way it is shown? If yes, how would I approach this?


I would like to use `keepalived` for failover purposes between the 2 HAProxy instances and have them do the load balancing for the backend farms. Kinda confused right now about the multiple virtual IP addresses I need to use, any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, HAproxy will do that.  You'll just need to configure keepalived with all of the virtual IPs that HAproxy will use.  You can assign multiple IPs in the virtual_ipaddress block in keepalived.conf:

```
virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.0.10
        192.168.0.11
        192.168.0.12
        192.168.0.13
        }
```